# Why does this not compile in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Why does this work:

```
if ("xx".StartsWith("x"))
{

}
```

But this doesn't:

```
if ("xx" + "xx".StartsWith("x"))
{

}
```

Compiler says error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: Woa, looks like people are going for "largest amount of identical answers to a question".

Comment: Why was this voted up so many times?  Its a horrible question, shows a complete lack of statement of boolean expressions, and evidence that not matter how detailed an error message is some people simply do not read them.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The member access operator `.` has higher priority than the `+` operator.

Check [C# Operators (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=VS.100).aspx) for the C# operator priorities. In particular it lists `x.y` as "primary" which is higher than binary `+` in "additive".

This means `"xx" + "xx".StartsWith("x")` is interpreted as
 `"xx" + ("xx".StartsWith("x"))` and that doesn't compile. It concats a `string` and a `bool` which gives you a `string`. But you can't use a `string` as a condition in an `if` statement since it's not `bool` (and doesn't implement the `true` operator either)

It seems you expected it to be interpreted as `("xx" + "xx").StartsWith("x"))` where you first concat the strings and then call `StartsWith` on the combined string.

Answer (score 18):

Because in the second case you try to compile such code:

```
 if ("xx" + true)
 {
 }
```

Comment: Which really is this: `if("xx" + true.ToString())`

Comment: @Kyle: Nonsense. string + bool automatically calls `ToString()` on the bool

Comment: @Kyle:  you're mistaken.  The compiler error is because an `if` statement requires a boolean expression.  The boolean `true` has `ToString()` called on it because it is being concatenated with another string.  The result of that concatenation is also a string, which cannot be implicitly converted to a bool, and therefore the `if` statement is invalid.

Comment: @Kyle:  go type `string x = "true" + true;` into VS and it will compile.

Answer (score 16):

Wrap it in Parens

```
if (("xx" + "xx").StartsWith("x"))
{

}
```

The reason for the error is that a `string` plus a `bool` = a `string`, and the if statement is expecting a `bool`.

Comment: This is slightly incorrect.  The reason for the error is that an `if` statement requires a boolean expression, and the OP is passing the result of a string concatenation (another string) to the `if` statement.  You can "concatenate" a string and a bool, because the bool will have `ToString()` called on it when compiled.

Comment: Actually, the error is "Cannot implicitly cast string to bool." This is because you cannot cast "xx".StartsWith() (a bool result) to "xx" (a string). *That* is the cause of the exception. Wrapping in parentheses *does* handily solve the problem, because it eliminates the casting issue by performing the concatenation before StartsWith is invoked.

Answer (score 5):

Because the Compiler is evaluating function-calls first, so he will try to concatenate `"xx"` with `true`:

```
if("xx" + "xx".StartsWith("x")) {
// becomes
if("xx" + true) {
```

This implicit conversion is not possible during runtime. You'll need to tell the compiler to concatenate the strings first:

```
if(("xx" + "xx").StartsWith("x")) {
```

Answer (score 5):

It has to do with the precedence of operators. In your case, StartsWith returns bool and when combined with a string addition string + bool does not return a bool, it returns a string while the if ( ) expects a bool.

You can change the precedence of operations by using parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

`"xx".StartsWith("x")` returns a boolean value, but `"xx" + "xx".StartsWith("x")` returns a string that would be either "xxTrue" or "xxFalse".

Comment: if you can tell me how "xx" + "xx".StartsWith("x") can return "xxFalse" i will give you a beer :)

Comment: @Gabriel somebody switched the default UTF code page? I was making the assumption that the OP was sanitizing their actual logic so "xx" is not the real value being tested and "x" is not the actual term being searched for.

Answer (score 2):

Because in the if statement a logical expression is expected not string.

Answer (score 2):

```
"xx".StartsWith("x")
```

is returning a `bool` and when you try and add "xx" to it, it's converting it to a `string`.

Change your code to

```
if (("xx" + "xx").StartsWith("x"))
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

if () expects a boolean value which your expression isnt.
This is in contrast from C/C++ which expects an int value as a condition.

Answer (score 0):

"xx" + "xx".StartsWith("x") is not a boolean expression. It evaluates to "xxTrue".

Answer (score 0):

The concatenation operator (+) is doing an implicit cast to a string in the second example. That example is also checking to see if a string is set not if it starts with something.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the `String.StartsWith()` method returns a boolean ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx)). So you are applying the `+` operator on a string and boolean, which doesn't work. If you wanted to concate the strings, then call `String.StartsWith()` on the newly created one; add some parenthesis:

```
if(("xx" + "xx").StartsWith("x"))
{

}
```

Hope this helps